# Handling multiple JWTs on client side to access multiple resource endpoints

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt

I am trying to get a sense of how I can handle juggling multiple JWT tokens on the frontend that will be accessing the same user agnostic api endpoints.

For example, I am calling two endpoints to get a JWT for the PrimaryUser and JWT for the SecondaryUser. On the backend, they are tied together as DualUsers. Inside of these tokens, I have the userId for each user.

I have multiple resource endpoints that will update based on the userId that is given in the JWT. I have about 100 of these.

On the front-end, I am currently overwriting the Authorization header whenever I need update one resource:

```
// updateUser(payload: object, config: RequestConfig)
// will update the user with primary user (default) Authorization header w/ JWT token
updateUser({firstName: 'Bob'})

// secondaryUserRequestConfig(): returns config with overriding Authorization w/ JWT tokens 
updateUser({firstName: 'Ted'}, secondaryUserRequestConfig)
```

The alternative would be to create a single JWT and have the backend handle explicit parameter for each `PrimaryUser.userId` and `SecondaryUser.userId`, but updating 100 endpoints seems like a lot. Is there a cleaner way to handle this case where I want to keep the backend endpoints relatively agnostic but also not have to pass in `secondaryUserRequestConfig`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to dynamically change axios config request,

using the URLs as a scope for endpoint 1 and endpoint 2, you can change their configuration by looking at the current url being requested:

```
import * as axios from "axios";

function createAxios() {
  let instance = axios.create();
  instance.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
      let [endpoint, url] = config.url.split("#");
      if (endpoint === "cat") {
        config.url = `https://api.thecatapi.com/${url}`;
        config.headers = {
          "X-Custom-Interceptor": "For Cat"
        };
      }
      if (endpoint === "anime") {
        config.url = `https://api.jikan.moe/${url}`;
      }
      return config;
    },
    function (error) {
      // Do something with request error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  return instance;
}


// Later in you code...
let remote = createAxios();

export default function App() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          remote.get("cat#v1/images/search")
        }}
      >
        Endpoint 1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          remote.get("anime#/v3/anime/1/episodes/1")
        }}
      >
        Endpoint 2
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

from there, you can attached any headers that you want,

i built a working example in:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2021-03-26-axios-with-interceptor-zs2zg?file=/src/App.js:0-1614

Comment: i think i'm going to go in a different direction. i have a bunch of these endpoints in an endpoints file, so i can't manipulate the urls themselves without passing in additional parameters. i think i'll extend the AxiosRequestConfig in order to accept isSecondaryUser and then set the Authorization headers that way. thank you for your response, but not quite what i was looking for...